Question on overlapping tabular
In my attempt to understand (very specific) nuances of LaTeX, I have a follow-up question to Question on overlapping parbox (concerning the baseline grid when a parbox is introduced). When backing up a line on a multi-row tabular environment, the lines do not overlap. With my very limited understanding, I suspect it's a similar problem to the referenced question, related to tabular setting \baselineskip to 0pt. The fix from the referenced question that worked perfectly for a parbox produces an Improper \prevdepth. error.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
Line One \\
Example - Line Two
\end{tabular}
\vskip -\baselineskip
Example

\end{document}



It's exactly the same problem: a top aligned tabular makes a \vtop, so all rows after the first one go in the depth.
Since the box has large depth, \lineskip enters the scene.
However you cannot record the depth like in \parbox. In a tabular all rows have the same height and depth as a \strut (unless the material is too tall or deep).
If the last line of the tabular isn't exceptional, you can issue \par and set the previous depth to that of a \strut.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
Line One \\
Example - Line Two
\end{tabular}\par\prevdepth=\dp\strutbox
\vskip -\baselineskip
\textcolor{red}{Example}

\end{document}


The little black dots you see in the picture are artifacts of the PDF viewer.

Thank you! It sure seemed similar to my last question, and thanks for explaining it!

Is there a similar fix for array?

@zgrizz The same? But, frankly, I don’t see what would be the use case.

Sorry, I should have clarified - a fix that works within math mode. I suppose there isn't a use beyond my interest in having all the lines spaced a certain way.
